# find specific weeks in month using php

Tags: php, date

I am tring to get the week from the month having starting Monday and end with Sunday with in same month.
i'll provide month and year.
for example:

```
$month = '03';
$year = '2014';
```

then function should return 
`2014-03-03 to 2014-03-09` as start date of month coz the month has its first Monday on 3rd.
then continue to month till last week.
In march, 2014, 31st starts on Monday but don't finish in march, it finishes at 06-04-2014 so this should not be included in counting.

Now, when i pass month as '04' than the month should count 31st march in its first week.

I hope i make my self clear, sorry for language.
I have tried so far:

```
$month = "04";
$year = "2014";
$beg = (int)date('W', strtotime("first day of $year-$month"));
$end = (int)date('W', strtotime("last day of $year-$month"));
$weeks = range($beg, $end);

foreach($weeks as $week) {
    $result = $this->getStartAndEndDate($week, $year);
    print_r($result);
}

function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year)
{
    $time = strtotime("1 January $year", time());
    $day = date('w', $time);
    $time += ((7*$week)+1-$day)*24*3600;
    $return[0] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
    $time += 6*24*3600;
    $return[1] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
    return $return;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2014-03-03
    [1] => 2014-03-09
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2014-03-10
    [1] => 2014-03-16
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2014-03-17
    [1] => 2014-03-23
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2014-03-24
    [1] => 2014-03-30
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2014-03-31
    [1] => 2014-04-06
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2014-04-07
    [1] => 2014-04-13
)
```

Comment: Why should it in one case be from 31.03. and in another not from 24.02. (where the week ends on 02.03.) - so how exactly are you solving "overlapping months"? Also where does your current code fail you?

Comment: @kingkero Exactly, its not just one case its just for an example..

Comment: In above output, I dont want last two arrays. also 2014-03-31 sholud count in April(04) 2014

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTime` class for this:

```
$dt = new DateTime('1st march');

// is this a monday?
if($dt->format('N') !== '1') {
  // if not, went to next monday
  $dt->modify('next monday');
}

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d')
    . ' to ' . $dt->modify('next sunday')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output:

```
2014-03-03 to 2014-03-09
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function get_weeks($month, $year) {
    $weeks = array();

    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mY', $month.$year);
    $date->modify('first Monday of this month');

    $end = clone $date;
    $end->modify('last Monday of this month');
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 week');
    $period = new DatePeriod($date, $interval, $end);

    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($period as $dt) {
        $end_of_week = clone $dt;
        $end_of_week->modify('next Sunday');
        $weeks[] = sprintf("Week %u: %s - %s", 
            $counter,
            $dt->format('Y-m-d'),
            $end_of_week->format('Y-m-d')
        );      
        $counter++;
    }

    return $weeks;
}
$weeks = get_weeks('03', '2014');
print_r($weeks);

Array
(
    [0] => Week 1: 2014-03-03 - 2014-03-09
    [1] => Week 2: 2014-03-10 - 2014-03-16
    [2] => Week 3: 2014-03-17 - 2014-03-23
    [3] => Week 4: 2014-03-24 - 2014-03-30
)
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/K0YDQc)