# Start counting weeks from specific month

Tags: php

Im trying to write php code which would start counting weeks from specific month. For me its September and February. For example desired result for 01.09.2017 would be Semester-1,Week-1. and for 04.09.2017 would be Semester-1,Week-2. I found similar topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840912/php-get-recurring-week-from-specific-start-date) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328423/find-specific-weeks-in-month-using-php) . But their output result is array, should i work with arreys here too ? I want to mention that I almost have zero expierence with php language.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
<?php
$day = date("D");
$month = date("M");
if($month == 'Apr'||'Feb'||'Mar'||'May') { 
print "Semester-2,"; 
}
else print "";
if($month == 'Sep'||'Oct'||'Nov'||'Dec') {
print "Semester-1,";
}
else print "";
if($month == 'Jan') { 
print "Exams"; 
}
if($month == 'Jun') { 
print "Exams,"; 
}
if($month == 'Jun') { 
print "Exams,"; 
}
if($month == 'Jul'||'Aug') { 
print "Summer Break,"; 
}
```

Comment: `$month == 'Sep'||'Oct'` doesn't work as you think, it needs to be `$month == 'Sep' || $month == 'Oct'` etc, alternatively just do `if (in_array($month, array("Apr", "Feb", "Mar", "May"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$month = date('n'); // Month number 1-12

if ($month >= 9 && $month <=12) {
    $period = 'Semester-1';
    $startWeek = date('W', strtotime(date('Y') . '-09-01'));
} elseif ($month >= 2 && $month <=5) {
    $period = 'Semester-2';
    $startWeek = date('W', strtotime(date('Y') . '-02-01'));
} elseif ($month == 1) {
    $period = 'Exams';
    $startWeek = date('W', strtotime(date('Y') . '-01-01'));
} elseif ($month == 6) {
    $period = 'Exams';
    $startWeek = date('W', strtotime(date('Y') . '-06-01'));
} elseif ($month == 7 || $month == 8) {
    $period = 'Summer break';
    $startWeek = date('W', strtotime(date('Y') . '-07-01'));
}

$currentWeek = date('W') - $startWeek + 1;

echo $period . ' ' . 'Week-' . $currentWeek;
```

Answer (score 0):

After @Qirel comment, I thought of something like this, hope this helps :

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$month = date("M"); /* current month */

if (in_array($month, array("Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))) { $myperiod = "Semester #1"; }

if (in_array($month, array("Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"))) { $myperiod = "Semester #2"; }

if($month == 'Jan') { $myperiod = "Mid-Exams #1"; }

if($month == 'Jun') { $myperiod = "Final-Exams #2"; }

if( ($month == 'Jul') || ($month == 'Aug') ) { $myperiod = "Summer break"; }

$today = date("Y-m-d"); /* or use your date from user data */
$date = new DateTime($today);
$week = $date->format("W"); /* use of PHP function 'date' to get week # */

$currentweek = "$week";

echo "[ Week # $week ]";

echo"You currently are in : $myperiod - $currentweek";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need:

```
$semesters = array(
    'Sep' => 'Semester-1',
    'Oct' => 'Semester-1',
    'Nov' => 'Semester-1',
    'Dec' => 'Semester-1',
    'Jan' => 'Exams',
    'Feb' => 'Semester-2',
    'Mar' => 'Semester-2',
    'Apr' => 'Semester-2',
    'May' => 'Semester-2',
    'Jun' => 'Exams',
    'Jul' => 'Summer Break',
    'Aug' => 'Summer Break',
);

switch ($semesters[date('M')]) {
    case 'Semester-1':
        $sep1st = strtotime('2017-09-01');
        $week1 = date('W', $sep1st);

        $currentWeek = date('W');

        echo 'Semester-1, Week-', $currentWeek - $week1 + 1; // +1 because the count starts at 1.

        break;

    case 'Semester-2':
        $feb1st = strtotime('2018-02-01');
        $week1 = date('W', $feb1st);

        $currentWeek = date('W');

        echo 'Semester-2, Week-', $currentWeek - $week1 + 1; // +1 because the count starts at 1.

        break;

    default:
        echo $semesters[date('M')];

        break;
}
```

Note that this can be refactored into smaller, more semantic parts.